24.04 change to mount command
Previously the following would mount a share that exists on a ubuntu 20.04 system:
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=guest,password=,rw,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,noperm //fossa/den /media/fossa

If given from a new 24.04 system, the command fails with error 22, invalid argument and, it is demanding a password for guest.
What is wrong with my mount command as used on a ubuntu 24.04 system?

I can now mount the share

My original example was incorrect.  Prior to version 18.04, password is spelled passwd.  When creating my new system, I had copied from an old (prior to 18.04) sample.  I have edited my answer here to reflect the mount command I use on a Ubuntu 24.04 system to access a share on a Ubuntu 22.04 system.
The share definition might also be a consideration.  In my example, no password is needed nor is it requested.
The working mount command is:
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=guest,password=,rw,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,noperm //fossa/den /media/fossa

The smb.conf which defines the share contains:
  [den]  
      path = /home/den  
      browseable = yes  
      read only = no  
      guest ok = yes  
      create mask = 0666  
      directory mask = 0777  
      force user = neil  
      force group = neil  


So is the code in the question actually correct?

Wording in the question reflects the current way a mount command looks

Ok, but is it correct? You say that the option is now spelled password, and that's what the command in question has.

Can you mount now, or not? If not, this should not be posted as an answer. Edit the question with this info.

I can now mount the share
